# Format of the data returned by the FTP LIST command?

Tags: list, ftp, command, format

I'm in the middle of writing an FTP server but I'm a little confused about what format to send the file list in.

Using 2 terminals and an FTP client, I was able to run through a simple FTP exchange. However, I wasn't really sure what format to send the file lists in.

Is there some accepted format? What columns should I use?

Comment: I don't believe this *is* anything resembling a standard. Different servers give different outputs, they're supposed to be human-readable rather than machine-readable.

Comment: @skaffman nice comment, but this should be an answer, not a comment, so that others can vote for it.

Comment: @skaff: Then how are graphical FTP clients supposed to interpret them?

Comment: @George They try to guess the output format and parse it. Some clients recognize hundreds of formats.

Comment: @George: By recognising all the various possibilities.

Comment: @skaffman: What value do human-readable listings have? Do people connect to FTP servers directly with telnet? It isn't making sense.

Comment: @george: FTP is ancient, remember. FTP clients would just dump the `dir` listing to the user's console, they had no need to actually understand it.

Comment: @skaffman: But then wouldn't the user need two terminals? One for the control connection and one for the data connection?

Comment: @George: No, they'd use an FTP client that manages the connections for them, not raw telnet.

Answer (score 4):

This is what the [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) has to say:

> The data transfer is over the data connection in type ASCII or type EBCDIC.  (The user must ensure that the TYPE is appropriately ASCII or EBCDIC). Since the information on a file may vary widely from system to system, this information may be hard to use automatically in a program, but may be quite useful to a human user.

So, the result is *not* expected to be automatically parsed.

Comment: Then how do graphical FTP clients enumerate files?

Comment: @George Edison - they _probably_ have a list of commonly used formats and parse those.

Comment: @George Edison - See the answer from @Eugene Mayevsky, these are apparently done through _extensions_ to the FTP standard.

Comment: @NathanOsman - I looked into the code of FileZilla on Sourceforge, and... it's not pretty, heh. Trial and error of about a dozen different formats.

Answer (score 4):

The standard doesn't define format of the directory listing sent/received using LIST command. Most servers use Unix listing format (don't know if it's defined in any document, but it's rather simple to generate and parse), some use DOS/Windows format. Other formats (over 400 as far as I know) are used worldwide, but the Unix one has become a standard de-facto.

Now there's important thing to implement: MLST and LMSD extension commands, defined in [RFC 3659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659). They define a way to produce and obtain machine-readable listing, which is very welcome in any modern FTP server.

Answer (score 2):

The RFC is poor there, but there are some nice links:

https://files.stairways.com/other/ftp-list-specs-info.txt

http://cr.yp.to/ftp/list/binls.html